# Linking to Files in Root Directory Outside of WP Installation

Tags: javascript, subdomains

I have a website that uses WordPress for its blog (the website itself is not WordPress). So the structure is:

```
 www.website.com (not WordPress)
 www.website.com/blog (WordPress)
```

I have a JavaScript file that is used for both the website and the blog. But when I link to the file in the functions.php file, WordPress tries to find it in the theme:

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script('circle-bounce', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/general.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-effects-core', 'jquery-effects-bounce'));
```

This looks for the general.js file in the folder for the wordpress child theme. In the source, it links to:

```
http://www.website.com/blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/general.js?ver=4.2.2
```

I actually need it to get the file inside the js folder in the root of the website. So the file can actually be found at:

```
website.com/js/general.js
```

The only way I've managed to achieve this is to change the registration to:

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script('circle-bounce', 'http://www.website.com/js/general.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-effects-core', 'jquery-effects-bounce'));
```

I'd like to avoid an absolute link if I can. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt does not work because `get_template_directory_uri` returns the URL to your theme directory.

Your second attempt will work, but if you don't want to hard code the domain you could either try using a root relative path or fetching the domain portion of your site url.

Relative path:

```
wp_register_script('circle-bounce', '/js/general.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-effects-core', 'jquery-effects-bounce'));
```

Domain:

```
$parts = parse_url(site_url());
$domain_url = $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'];
wp_register_script('circle-bounce', $domain_url . '/js/general.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-effects-core', 'jquery-effects-bounce'));
```

Comment: I tried root relative and it ends up thinking that the subdomain is the root. With the relative path, it actually links to www.website.com/blog/js/general.js. It should be going to the actual root: www.website.com/js/general.js.

Comment: The script that you provided works. What is the dollar sign for? Is it JavaScript or something else?

Comment: In PHP all variables are declared using a `$`. As in `$myVar = 'test';`. In this case `$parts` and `$domain_url` are variables.